# How to leave a placeholder within a variable to be filled later using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

On paper this paper this seems like a very simple operation, but for some reason Javascript does not seem to like it. Basically I have the following code:

```
var news = "<b>" + place_name + ", " + county + ""<img id = 'centre' src=" + picture + ">" + "</b><ul><br>";
```

The general idea is that picture is a variable that will be filled later via:

```
news.picture = entry2.picture;
```

which is a link to provide to the img source. However, when I do:

```
console.log(news.picture);
```

The variable remains undefined. Is this the correct way to go about things?

Comment: I'd check your syntax first -- `", " + county + ""<img...` is not correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

news is a variable made out of strings and variables.

So you cant use news.picture.

Though you can make the variable a function object.

```
var news = function() }
    this.picture = "something";

    this.getString = function() {
        return this.picture+"some string";
    };
};
```

Then you can get and set the picture variable inside news with news.picture and get the string with news.getString().

Comment: Using `new` as a variable is not going to work very well.

Comment: My bad, made a typos should be news ;)

Comment: Also made getString into a proper function with return. Answering questions half awake :P

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way you are supposed to do that. You have to have your variables set and then you can construct a string like that.

What you need now, is basically a function, like this:

```
var createNews = function(place_name,county,picture)  {
  return "<b>" + place_name + ", " + county + "<img id = 'centre' src=" + picture + ">" + "</b><ul><br>";
}
var news = createNews("Place","county","pic.jpg");
console.log(news);
```

Or you can do it like this, if you prefer:

```
var createNews = function(obj) {
    return "<b>" + obj.place_name + ", " + obj.county + "<img id = 'centre' src=" + obj.picture + ">" + "</b><ul><br>";
}
var news = {
    place_name : "Someplace",
    county : "Somewhere",
    picture : "foo.png"
};
var newsItem = createNews(news);
console.log(newsItem);
```